# Issues breaking up huge CSV file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

[Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2qgd.png) I am trying to break up a large CSV file into smaller ones. Original file: 5,055,000 lines of excel data. Desired file: 500,000 lines of data per file. However, there are 2 recurring errors that I absolutely cannot solve, no matter what.

What I am trying to do, is open a CSV file, import up to 500,000 lines, and immediately export them into a series of new CSV files, making a new file for each 500k.

```
$sourceCSV = "E:\Data\032110-26AM.CSV"
$startrow = 0 ;
$counter = 1 ;
while ($startrow -lt5055000)
{

Import-CSV $sourceCSV | select-object -skip $startrow -first 500000 | Export-CSV "E:\Data\032110-26AM_SPLITFILE2$($counter).csv" -NoClobber;

$startrow += 500000 ;
$counter++ ;
}
```

I expected the code to go through my file, and create 11 smaller files. However, I get the following errors:

```
At line:7 char:62
+ ... mport-CSV $sourceCSV | select-object -skip $startrow -first <500000>  ...
+                     ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that avoids hard-coding the numbers used inside the loop. Tested on a CSV with 500 lines. Adjust to fit your file paths, numbers, etc...

```
$sourceCSV = "C:\scripts\test.csv"
$startrow = 0
$endrow = 500
$readcount = 50
$counter = 1
while ($startrow -lt $endrow)
{
Import-CSV $sourceCSV | Select-Object -Skip $startrow -First $readcount | Export-CSV $("C:\scripts\test_"+"$counter.csv") -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
$startrow = $startrow + $readcount
$counter++
}
```

Your usage may or may not need the `-NoTypeInformation`, but I find it can be helpful if you're going to feed the results into something other than another PowerShell script since many tools don't recognize the format with the extra line of info at the top.

Coincidentally, your original "CSV" file is polluted with some extra lines at the top, so you will need to get rid of them first. Here is a way to do that, keeping in line with my original answer. I've also added an adjustment to account for unpredictable file sizes as requested.

```
$initialsourceCSV = "C:\scripts\testwithjunk.csv"
$initialskip = 6
Get-Content $initialsourceCSV | Select-Object -Skip $initialskip | Out-File -FilePath "C:\scripts\temp.csv"
$sourceCSV = "C:\scripts\temp.csv"
$startrow = 0
$endrow = (get-content $sourceCSV).Length
$readcount = 50
$counter = 1
while ($startrow -lt $endrow)
{
Import-CSV $sourceCSV | Select-Object -Skip $startrow -First $readcount | Export-CSV $("C:\scripts\test_"+"$counter.csv") -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
$startrow = $startrow + $readcount
$counter++
}
Remove-Item "C:\scripts\temp.csv"
```